# How to properly write an NgModel form inside another ngFor table

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table of students I'm getting from the database, and I'm trying to make a 'POST' form for each student if he's absent that get sent to the 'absences' table in my database, just like this :
[image]

the problem is when i select the radio button for 'Absent' all the radio buttons get selected and when i write an input in the 'teacher comment' it gets written in all the inputs of the table,

How can I fix this so each row of my table have his own post function

this is my component.ts

```
contacts: [];
  upadateform = {
    'dc_docjustificatif': File = null,
    'dc_student': '',
    'dc_status': null,
    'dc_description':''
    
  }

  constructor(private contactsService : contactsService,
    private absenceService : absenceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.contactsService.fetchAll()
      .subscribe(
        res => this.contacts = res,
        
      )
  }
  addAbsence(){
    this.absenceService.postAbsence(this.upadateform)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        
        
      }
    )     
  };
```

this is my component.html

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let contact of contacts ; let i = index">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne"  *ngIf="contact._dc_class_value==='81745753-a826-ec11-b6e5-002248131c68'">
      <form #absenceform="ngForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="row ">
          <!--Execution-->
          <div class="col-1 mt-2">
            {{i-1}}
          
        </div> 
          <div   class="col-3 mt-2"> 
            {{contact.fullname}}
          </div>
          
           
        <div class="col-2 mt-2">
          CL1_Pro1
        
        </div>
        <div class="col-1  mt-2  ml-3">
          <input [(ngModel)]="upadateform.dc_status" [value]="100000000"  class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios{{i}}" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 mt-2 ml-3">

          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios{{i}}" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2" >
        
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 mt-2 ml-3">
          <input [(ngModel)]="upadateform.dc_status"  [value]="100000002" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios{{i}}" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3" >
        
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 mt-2">
        <input name="Name{{ i }}" id="Name{{ i }}"
        class="input-group input-group-sm" width="50%" [(ngModel)]="upadateform.dc_description">
        </div>
        <button (click)="addAbsence()" class="mt-2 btn btn-danger shape float-right">
          Save
          </button>
          
        </div>
      </form>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have this

```
name="exampleRadios{{i}}" id="exampleRadios1"
```

you have a lot of elements with the same name and the same id

Comment: I dont think that's the problem, the middle select column of 'present' where there isnt an [(ngModel)] value works fine

Comment: Try to use the checked property to set the status of the radio input like checked=true/false based on contacts status and check the [(ngModel)] working

Comment: that's not what i needed, I want to make my rows diiferent because right now each row has the same values, if you look at the 'teacher comment' input when i type something in one row, it gets passed to all the other rows