# Angular 9 typescript Create Multiple Objects in a Loop with different names

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to dynamicly declare multiple objects according to the length of the table 'contacts'
for example

```
contacts: [];
//lets say contacts.length is 3 so i want to dynamicly declare 3 updateforms like this:
upadateform1 = {
    'dc_student': '',
    'dc_status': null,
    'dc_description':''
    
  }
upadateform2 = {
    'dc_student': '',
    'dc_status': null,
    'dc_description':''
    
  }
upadateform3 = {
    'dc_student': '',
    'dc_status': null,
    'dc_description':''
    
  }
```

How can i do that with for loop or something?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of would be this array of objects:

```js
const genericObjectBody = {
  dc_student: '',
  dc_status: null,
  dc_description:''
};

const arr = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  arr.push({ ['updateForm' + i]: { ...genericObjectBody } });
}

console.log(arr);
```

Though I'm curious as to why a simple array without the `updateForm{i}` wouldn't be sufficient?

You could name the array `updateForms` and if you require to retrieve a value, applying the index to the array would retreive whatever "update form" you require.

Comment: this is the problem i was facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562022/how-to-properly-write-an-ngmodel-form-inside-another-ngfor-table/ ... i thought if i declare multiple object it will solve it

Comment: Also I cant put that code inside my component class